# Flutter 2.0: The return Type <List<LatLng>> isn’t a 'void', as required by the closure's context

Tags: dart, sdk, flutter2.0

I am getting the error
`The return Type <List<LatLng>> isn’t a 'void', as required by the closure's context`
regarding the line `return polygonList;` in this button widget:

```
Widget _markerButton(BuildContext context) {
  return IconButton(
    icon: Icon(Icons.favorite, color: _list ? Colors.green : Colors.red),
    onPressed: () {
      setState(() {
        _list = !_list;
        numberOfMarkers(latlng)[0];
        realtyTap = true;
      });
      return polygonList;
    },
  );
}
```

It worked excellent before. This error appeared when I switched to Flutter 2.0 and `sdk: "> = 2.12.0 <3.0.0”` .

I looked at the answers to questions from people with similar difficulties, but it did not help me.

The whole page code is:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

import 'package:flutter_map/flutter_map.dart';
import 'package:latlong/latlong.dart';


class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function state;
  HomePage(this.state);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  late MapController _mapController;
  late LatLng latlng;

  List<Marker> markers = [];
  List<LatLng> polygonList = [];

  bool singleTap = false;
  bool _list = false;

  double maxZoom = 6.0;
  double minZoom = 4.0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  Widget _markerButton(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.favorite, color: _list ? Colors.green : Colors.red),
      onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
          _list = !_list;
        });
        return polygonList;
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      body: FlutterMap(
        mapController: _mapController,
        options: MapOptions(
            center: LatLng(40.000000, 70.000000),
            zoom: 4,
            onTap: (latlng) {
              if (singleTap) {
                setState(() {
                  if (markers.length == 0) {
                    markers.add(Marker(
                        point: latlng,
                        builder: (context) => _markerButton(context)));
                  } else {
                    markers.add(
                      Marker(
                        point: latlng,
                        builder: (ctx) => const Icon(
                          Icons.fiber_manual_record_rounded,
                          color: Colors.red,
                          size: 15.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  }
                  polygonList.add(latlng);
                });
              }
            }),
        layers: [
          TileLayerOptions(
              urlTemplate: "https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
              subdomains: ['a', 'b', 'c']),
          PolygonLayerOptions(
            polygons: [
              Polygon(
                points: polygonList,
                borderStrokeWidth: 3.0,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

What should be happened here: if the user clicks for the second time the point from which s/he started building the polygon on the map, the button change its color, the building stops, and a list of points in the corners of the constructed polygon is returned.

I would be grateful if you could give me some advice on how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dart 2.12 added stricter type checking to catch cases where callbacks return unused values.

[`IconButton.onPressed`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/IconButton/onPressed.html) is a `VoidCallback?`; that is, if it isn't `null`, it is a function that returns nothing.

You are supplying an anonymous function that has `return polygonList;` in it.  That returned value can never be used, so the `return` statement is useless.  Simply remove it.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I understand what happened. But I need to return polygonList when this button is pressed, because I use it later. How to do it by another way?

Comment: Return it to what?  Nothing ever uses the return value.  You said that the code worked before, so it should continue working when you remove the unused line.

Comment: oh sorry, maybe I should include all my code as it is. I just took out some parts to make it shorter. Please, look at this gist)) https://gist.github.com/kotrotko/2841b9684857c55f415b0029516ee3ab

Comment: As I said, just remove the line. It never did anything. If your code isn't working, then you have some separate problem (which you should describe and ask about in a separate question).

Comment: Thank you! Sorry again, "late ignition")) I got it)))